# querying key value pair design table using EF

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a table which is similar to Key-Value pair design structure. I would like to query the table based on the key and value, but I am facing some problem. Below is my table structure and expected output.

> Table 1:
>
> ## ID   KEY VALUE
>
> ```
> 1   NAME        abc
> 2   AGE         12
> 3   DEPARTMENT  CCB
> 4   NAME        xyz
> 5   AGE         13
> 6   DEPARTMENT  TSS
> 7   NAME        cde
> 8   AGE         12
> 9   DEPARTMENT  TMS
> ```

```
Table 2:

KeyId KeyName
1      Name
2      Department
3      Age
```

for easy understanding I entered directly the key names in Table 1, actually there exists a foreign key relation between table 1 and table 2.

Also table 2 can hold anything as KeyName not necessarily Name, Department and Age.

Expected output is : I need to get the data with the Name contains %c% and Age = 12.

```
     Name Age Department
     abc  12  CCB
     cde  12  TMS
```

NOTE: I am looking for a EF solution i.e., linq query, not sql query.

Options I tried out, below is the query:

var temp =  `(from c in table1` 
              `where c.Name.Contains("C") || C.Age == 12`
        `Select new { C.Name, C.Age })`

Thought of applying "OR" condition so that I get both the condition satisfied and then filter using "AND" in the in-memory once I fetch the data from database. But I was not able to succeed.

Comment: Your table is not properly designed at all. The names, ages and departments have no relation, thus it is almost impossible to write a query (in linq or sql) that will guarantee correct data. Consider redesigning your table.

Comment: @Mansfield I don't think you can tell that from one table.  DotNetNuke has a similar design for its ProfileProperties table.  There could be another table that has a list of IDs that link each user to IDs in this table.

Comment: @L_7337 The problem is, there is no mention of this other table, yet it is required for the question's "expected output" to be reliably generated. Without it, the only link between the 3 keys are their relative position in the table, which is weakly enforced and leads to unnecessarily inefficient and convoluted queries.

Comment: @Mansfield This kind of design is not something new, KVP design structured is being widely used, only thing is I am not able to query on it. Yes there exist another table with the keys, I will modify my post to include the other table as well.

Comment: @Abhinay If you have another table then it makes more sense. But the original table you posted **by itself** is not sufficient.

Comment: Question is already edited and the expected results are also posted clearly. Since I didn't had any solution for this I posted in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = input.Select((x,i)=>new {x,i})
                  .GroupBy(a=>a.i/3)
                  .Where(g=>g.FirstOrDefault().x.Value.Contains("c") &&
                            Convert.ToInt32(g.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().x.Value) == 12)
                  .Select(g=> new {
                             Name = g.FirstOrDefault().x.Value,
                             Age = Convert.ToInt32(g.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().x.Value),
                             Department = g.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault().x.Value
                          });
```

Not sure if it works in `EF` but looks like if it doesn't, you have to execute the query in client side with `AsEnumerable()` before appending any method after `input`.

Comment: We have an ID, so we should try to group on that instead of LINQ's index (`a.i`), in case the results come in a different order for whatever reason. Also you can use `ElementAt(x)` in place of `Skip(x).First()`.

Comment: @nmclean I'm not sure if `ElementAt` works in `EF`, for client-side `LINQ`, we can freely do many things, but for `LINQ to Entity`, we need experience to make sure it work, in fact I've not worked with `EF` much. For the `index`, I'm also not sure if the `ID` has that exact values, the only thing I'm sure is the order of rows should be `Name, Age, Department - Name, Age, Department - ...`